# Sprig add to cart display cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-sprig

products index.twig file include a Sprig component with filters:

```
{{ sprig('_components/productCategoryList.twig', { entryId: entry.id }) }}
```

productCategoryList.twig file includes a list of all products that can be filtered and also include am "add to cart button"

```
{% for product in products %}{{ sprig('_components/addToCart.twig', { productId: product.id }) }}{% endfor %}
```

addToCart.twig code:

```
<button
   sprig
   s-method="post"
   s-action="commerce/cart/update-cart"
   s-val:purchasable-id="{{ selectedVariant.id }}"
>
{{ "Add to Cart"|t }}
</button>

{% if success is defined %}
  {{ sprig.triggerRefreshOnLoad('.cart-count') }}
<script>
   htmx.toggleClass(htmx.find("#sprig-cart"), "hidden");
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Top navigation file working part:

```
<button _="on click toggle .hidden on #sprig-cart">
   <!-- cart svg icon -->
   <!-- shopping cart count -->
   {% if sprig.isRequest %}

     <span class="cart-count absolute">
       {% if craft.orders.number(cart.number).one() is not empty %}
         <span>{{ craft.orders.number(cart.number).one().totalQty ?? 0 }}</span>
       {% else %}
         <span>{{ craft.orders.number(cart.number).one().totalQty ?? 0}}</span>
       {% endif %}
     </span>

   {% else %}
     <span class="..."></span>
   {% endif %}
</button>
```

**Cart slide is not working as desired. The cart slide should only display when either clicking on the shopping cart icon in the navigation or when pressing the "addToCart" button. Right now it display on page load....**
My guess is nested sprig components issue but can't find how to fix that.

```
<!-- Cart slide in -->
<div id="sprig-cart" _="on closeCart add .hidden" class="hidden fixed inset-0 ...">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="fixed inset-0..."></div>
  <!-- Panel -->
  <div class="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 max-w-lg w-full">
    <div class="h-full w-full">
      <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
        <!-- Close Button -->
        <div _="on click trigger closeCart" class="absolute... ">
          <button _="on click trigger closeCart" class="...">close</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Body -->
        <div>
        {% if sprig.isRequest %}
           list of products in cart or no items message
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```